# How to add javascript to my php MVC framework

Tags: php, javascript, model-view-controller, frameworks

I created a simple PHP MVC framework and I'm familiar with PHP. I think I understand the basics of JavaScript, but I have no idea how to use it with my MVC framework. Right now I have a folder in my root directory called scripts, a file inside of it called javascript.js and I put the appropriate source thing in my template. All I want to do right now is make a simple confirm box in the admin panel before accepting/deleting an application to join my site. Obviously there are two buttons (accept/delete) and I use onclick to call a function (AdminModel::acceptApplication). This is the AdminModel:acceptApplication function up to this point:

```
    public function acceptApplication($id) {
    $confirm=AdminModel::confirm();
    if($confirm) {
        $mysqli = BaseModel::dbConnect();
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM applications WHERE id=" . $id;
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, email, password) VALUES (" . $row['fname'] . ", " . $row['lname'] . ", " . $row['email'] . ", " . $row['password'] . ")";
        mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

        $sql = "DELETE FROM applications WHERE id=" . $id;
        mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql);

        header('Location: http://www.canforce.org/' . $_SESSION['language'] . '/admin/applications');
    }
    public function confirm() {
    $confirm = echo '<script> areYouSure(); </script>';
    return($confirm);
     }
```

The JavaScript areYouSure() function returns true if you click yes:

```
function areYouSure() {
if(<?php echo $_SESSION['language'] ?> == "fr") {
    confirm("&Ecirc;tes-vous s&ucirc;r");
}
else {
    confirm("Are you Sure?");
}
```

}

I'm guessing there's allot wrong with what I've done here, simply bc of the whole server side/client side thing, but then I have no idea how to use javascript properly within my website. I want this to work, but if anybody has any tips or links to tutorial on how I can incorporate javascript into my php mvc framework, that would be appreciated as well. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at how other popular PHP MVC frameworks handles this? It's not too late to switch to another MVC - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sunk_costs

Comment: Please, learn to use prepared statements instead of simply replacing "mysql_" with "mysqli_". Also, javascript should be contained in external files, and not be dumped in the HTML. Oh ... and what you have there is **not** MVC.

Comment: zjd: I used to run a framework based on some Codon framework I think it is, but I want to learn how it all works and enjoy learning how it all works.

Comment: teresko: mysqli works perfectly fine for my needs unless there's some reason I'm not aware of. If you would have read my question thoroughly, u would have noticed that my javascript is in a separate file. It is MVC, I based it off a very good tutorial I found online. I haven't included the controller or the view code because they are irrelevant to the question (I do admit that maybe the confirm function doesn't technically belong there but it works for my purposes).

Comment: Do you even know what "prepared statements" are? And I won't even touch what you call "MVC". Here's a hint: "model" in MVC is not a class nor object. There are no *multiple models*. Model is a layer.

Comment: Im guessing prepared statements is that PDO stuff. That's what the tutorial originally showed it in, but I switched to MySQL bc I was more familiar with it, then to mysqli when I found the row_count thing didn't work in MySQL. Are there any advantages to PDO (obviously ill google it n see but I thought they did the same thing)? You've really confused me with this model being a layer thing can u explain more or provide a link or something? The tutorial I viewed showed it in a class, and that's also the way my old framework did it.

Comment: I've done some more reading and it turns out you're right. It isn't MVC, it's MVA at the moment. Turns out I didn't completely understand MVC but I think I do now and will be editing my website to conform to MVC standards. I did some quick reading on why PDO is better than mysqli, I plan to do some more reading on that and switch to it after I fully understand what it is. As for the javascript part, I think AJAX might be able to accomplish what I'm looking for. I still have no idea what you mean by model not being a class and being a layer, like I said a link would be nice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

PHP runs on a server. Javascript for the purpose of this conversation runs in the browser. You are trying to get the results of a browser level call on the server, another computer, it will not work. Your Model code exists on the server.

You need to have the js file included in your html file, in this case whatever passes for your view.

PS. The purpose of prepared statements is to prevent someone being able to run queries against your database, including deletes and getting all of your user info.